# А так - запятая, тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Как лучше оформить "А так"?

А **так,** не вопрос - деньжата лишними не будут. / А **так -** не вопрос, деньжата лишними не будут.

Я в этом месте недавно, и где магазинчик этот - без понятия. А так не вопрос - деньжата лишними не будут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы написала так:

*Я в этом месте недавно, и где магазинчик этот — без понятия. **А так** не вопрос,  деньжата лишними не будут.*

Это ***БСП***, значение причины.  Можно поставить любой знак (двоеточие, тире, запятую). Но стиль разговорный, поэтому достаточно запятой.

***А так*** — в значении "а в общем-то".